# How soft-actor-critic algorithm deal with policy gradient?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

So I was reading the soft-actor-critic paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.01290.pdf

The actor uses stochastic policy which samples from a distribution. A neural network is used to approximate the policy. Instead of really "sample" the action, the authors expand the input of the network to state plus a vector of noise.

```
at = fφ(x; st)
```

In which x is the noise vector, say [x1, x2]

Then the probability `πφ(at|s) is p(x1)*p(x2)`, I think.

Which means the entropy `log πφ(at|s)` is irrelative with parameter φ or at

Thus the policy gradient offered by the paper

```
∇φJπ(φ) = ∇φ log πφ(at|st)
+ (∇at log πφ(at|st) − ∇at Q(st, at)) * ∇φ fφ(x; st)
```

can be simplified to

```
∇φJπ(φ) = −∇at Q(st, at) * ∇φ fφ(x; st)
```

which is identical to DDPG.
So where did I make a mistake? Someone help me?